# Re-render router-view component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

The best way to re-render a component in Vue is to update its `key`. But what if I want to re-render a `<router-view>` component with this setup?

```js
<router-view :key="this.$route.params.slug"></router-view>
```

The routing is set up to use `/item/:slug`

If I change the `key` to force a re-render, all `<router-link>` elements inside the `<router-view>` component stop working. I've tried setting a key on a wrapping `<keep-alive>` element and updating it, but that doesn't re-render the `<router-view>`.

Any ideas?

*Edit:* Looks like the issue was `this.$route.params.slug`, when changed to `$route.params.slug` everything got back on track.

Comment: Looks good to me. What do you mean: "stop working"? Please add a minimal reproduction example.

Comment: @rx2347 I mean that clicks on the router-link elements stop working. The router doesn't update when trying to navigate using those elements.

Comment: Just noticed: it has to be $route.params.slug instead of this.$route.params.slug... if that doesnt fix it,  please provide a minimal example of your code, no way around it.

Comment: Nice catch! Seems like that pesky `this` was the issue here. Thanks!